# CRACK THIS CODE

Tags: cipher

"A letter from Pope Benedict V"

You need an exact row and column. One letter, two digits.

45-43-15/12-54/13-23-24-31-14-42-15-13/52-23-15-33/44-23-15-54/35-31-11-54/

45-43-15/12-54/23-45-32-11-33-43/52-23-15-33/44-23-15-54/43-31-11-54/

52-23-11-44/24-43/44-23-15/11-33-43-52-15-42/

Don't know the answer? What a shame!

Read again the letter, you might get a hint.

I challenge you to crack the code. Goodluck!

Comment: The "V" correct?  He wasn't Pope for long.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want a single letter answer, which I believe would be:

> t = 44

Which

> looks like a sword and is a letter within the name Pope Benedict V

Or a single word answer using the substitution:

> sword = 43-52-34-42-14

which

> he predicted would devastate Hamburg after his death

The cipher is:

> Polybius square

And the decode (which at this time has an error) is:

> use by childrec (sic) when they play, use by humans when they slay, what is the answer

I think the last duple in the third set of the first line should be 31 not 13.